# how to clear serial buffer?

Tags: winapi, serial-port, buffer-overflow

I am receiving messages over serial port from a micro-controller. i am using a baud rate of 9600. I have a program written using win32 API that receives the messages. Sometimes it happens that i am not able to receive the messages and then suddenly a burst comes in when i press Ctrl+C.
How do I clear the serial buffer so that i can avoid this flooding of data?

Thank you

Comment: A good way to clear the serial buffer is to read bytes from it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`PurgeComm` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363428.aspx) does that.

When using serial ports in Windows, [the Comm Port API reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363195.aspx) is quite useful.