# Windows does not flush COM-Buffer

Tags: c++, windows, serial-port, virtual-serial-port

I'm seeing some pretty odd behaviour from windows regarding my COM-Buffers.

I use 3 USB-Serial Converter with FTDI chips. I open the com ports with `CreateFile` and it all works fine. All 3 ports have the same configuration except for the baud rates. 2 work at 38400 and one at 9600.

Here is the odd part:

I am able to successfully write out of the 9600 port and one of the 38400 port. The second 38400 ports seems to be buffering the data. I have connected to this port with Hyperterminal and see that on the working ports i immediately get a response and on the "weird" port i only get the data when i close my application...

Has anyone else experienced this? How did you resolve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to clear serial buffer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5453205/how-to-clear-serial-buffer)

Comment: Not a duplicate - that question is about reading, not writing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is kind of a shot in the dark... but.

Check the flow control settings for both ends of the "weird" connection. I've seen strange things like this when the flow control is mismatched. The act of closing the port clears the bits and allows the buffered data to flow.

Answer (score 0):

Having worked a bit with FTDI chips, I would suggest you check out the advanced driver settings for each port. The driver supports both buffering and latency control in order to allow you to compromise between high throughput and low latency. So check the settings that work and use the same for the one that doesn't (if they're not the same).

On a side note, by using FTDI:s own [API](http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/ProgramGuides/D2XX_Programmer%27s_Guide%28FT_000071%29.pdf) you don't have to keep track of COM-port reassignment and the like. The API is quite similar to the normal Win32 one but exposes more configuration options.

Comment: very nice, but the app is done. If i ever need to change anything i might use it. Thx.